# Selenium: FindsBy with collection

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, readonly-collection

I am a beginner in testing and have a question. How can I correctly use `ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>`if I use attribute `FindsBy` . My collection is always null after started test. Heres is my code in C#:

```
        [FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "role")]
        public ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> radPercentage { get; }
```

and here is testing web: http://testwisely.com/demo/survey

I want to do something like this:  `radPercentage[2].Click();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call **InitElements** before using the collection. Pass the driver and an instance of a class containing the *FindsBy* properties (in my code "this").

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://testwisely.com/demo/survey");
PageFactory.InitElements(driver, this);
IWebElement radio = this.radPercentage[2];
```

The method InitElements is expecting the property to be of type **IWebElement** or **IList** of **IWebElement**

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "role")]
public IList<IWebElement> radPercentage;
```

Comment: Once the page elements are initialized, can you refresh a particular element by using `PageFactory.InitElements(driver, radPercentage)'` ?

Comment: For refreshing the elements you not only need to call the method again but also visiting the page. Not sure if there's a shortcut for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public void FindStuff()
{
    var stuff = driver.FindElements(By.Name("role"));
    stuff[2].Click();
}
```